# Do monsters walk back through Town Portals in Diablo fiction?

Tags: video-games, adaptations, diablo

In the Diablo I, II, and III video games, the character can create a town portal to come back to town and sell the loot they have aquired, rest, heal up, etc.

I know, at least I think I do, that the inability for monsters to use the town portal is never addressed in the game, and thus this question should not be about the games.

*Is it addressed in any of the novelizations or other extended universe media*? Are the denizens of hell able to do so in the novels?

Comment: Based on a couple meta questions, I think this falls into the purvue of game-play questions and would be off-topic. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/319/can-i-ask-a-question-about-video-game-based-scifi-fantasy  and  http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/400/which-mediums-can-be-the-basis-of-questions

Comment: @BBlake I'm not concerned about the game-play aspect of it. The Diablo worlds exist outside of the games, and that's more what I'm interested in *whether* it comes as a comment about the games by developers, in the novel or wherever.

Comment: It is probably because Cain would talk them to death if they did.

Comment: Stay a while, and listen...

Comment: @Pureferret - Inferno at you

Comment: Do you have a specific instance of the Scroll of Town Portal being used in non-game media?

Comment: @user13095 No I don't

Comment: Well.. not canon, but sorta on topic and funny: http://www.dorkly.com/video/28510/dorkly-bits-how-diablo-destroyed-tristram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only portals mentioned in the various Diablo books I've read are demonic portals, not town portals (yet to read the Diablo III fiction).  In fact Town Portal usage seems to be limited to the game.

If you're looking for a canon answer we can only extrapolate from the games themselves - since the monsters don't go through Town Portals in the game, we have to assume that if someone used such a spell in the fiction they wouldn't be able to go through.

Comment: Wat I was really hoping for was something concrete in the fiction, to pin down what seemed ambiguous in the games. But is nothing concree exist, then I'll have to go with this!

Comment: I don't think it's ambiguous in the games - throw up a Town Portal in the middle of half a million monsters in any of the games and walk through... none will follow you, yet those same monsters will follow you for miles if you run away. :)

Comment: Demons are extra-planar so it possibly explains why they can't go through the portals. The undead however...it's tougher to explain why they can't. Other than saying that the portal is restricted to living beings from this plane.

Comment: It's also worth noting that "Town Portal" is somewhat of a game trope. It's not specific to Diablo; more specific to the RPG genre. This might explain the lack of presence in written fiction.

Answer (score 4):

In multiplayer in Diablo 2, access is party members only. Preventing those hostile to the caster from using the portal.

An argument can be made for extrapolating from there that the portals can only be used by those allied with, or allowed by, the caster, in either case preventing monster access.

Comment: This is a nice and well reasoned first answer! It is worth noting that the asker is looking for book answers over game answers so if you know of anything from those that is relevant [edit]ing it in will make this answer even stronger than it already is!

Answer (score 3):

The [lore](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Town_Portal#Lore) indicates that these gates (or the practice to create the gates) were created by the Horadrim

> The Horadrim constructed numerous magical gateways between the mighty fortresses so that they could quickly concentrate their defenses against any incursion by the Demons. With but a thought, the Crusaders of the Light could transport themselves to predetermined destinations many leagues apart. Although the secret of creating these gateways has been long lost, it is still possible to use the pathways that are already in place. A Portal opened by means of this spell will always take the caster to the location of the nearest gate and remain open long enough to bring the caster back to his point of origin. The Church of Tristram is built upon the remains of a Horadrim monastery, and it is quite probable that a gateway lies nearby.

The Horadrim were dedicated to removing the demons from Sanctuary, to the point where they led the hunt to capture and seal the Prime Evils. There is no hard evidence to say that a demon *cannot* use these portals, but due to their prowess in magic, and their dedication to eradicating the demon incursion, it is very likely that they were created with the protection against demon usage.

Comment: i have the book of cain somewhere, and if I can dig it up I'll let you know what I find.